# My Trigger ORA-00904: "ID_PENDAFTAR": invalid identifier

Tags: database, netbeans, oracle10g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pendaftaran_tri 
BEFORE INSERT ON    MAHASISWA   
FOR EACH ROW  

WHEN (new.id_pendaftar is null)  
DECLARE      v_daftar mahasiswa.id_pendaftar%NUMBER(8,0); 
BEGIN

 SELECT MAHASISWA_SEQ.nextval INTO v_daftar 
FROM DUAL;   :new.id_pendaftar := v_daftar;  

END pendaftaran_tri;
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE  "MAHASISWA" ( 
"id_pendaftar" NUMBER(6,0), 
"nama_mhs" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"nim" NUMBER(11,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"id_pembayaran" VARCHAR2(8), 
"jenis_kel" VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"goldar" VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"tem_lahir" VARCHAR2(18) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ttl" DATE, 
"alamat_mhs" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"no_telp" VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"email_mhs" VARCHAR2(35) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"kd_jurusan" VARCHAR2(4), 
"no_rek" VARCHAR2(16), 
"pin" VARCHAR2(6), 
CONSTRAINT "PK_MAHASISWA" PRIMARY KEY ("nim") ENABLE, 
CONSTRAINT "MAHASISWA_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_KAMPUS")
REFERENCES  "KAMPUS" ("id_kampus") ENABLE
   )

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "UPDATE_MAHASISWA_HISTORY" 
AFTER UPDATE ON MAHASISWA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  add_mahasiswa_history(:old.id_pendaftar, :old.ID_KAMPUS, sysdate,
:old.nim, :old.nama_mhs, :old.id_pembayaran, :old.jenis_kel, :old.goldar, :old.tem_lahir, :old.ttl, :old.alamat_mhs, :old.no_telp, :old.email_mhs, :old.kd_jurusan, :old.no_rek, :old.pin );
END;

CREATE SEQUENCE   "MAHASISWA_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE

ALTER TRIGGER  "UPDATE_MAHASISWA_HISTORY" ENABLE;
/
ALTER TRIGGER  "UPDATE_MAHASISWA_HISTORY" ENABLE
/
```

Comment: Could you add more text to your problem?  And try formatting your code?  How is the table defined that the trigger is running against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CREATE TABLE statement contains the column names in double quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE  "MAHASISWA" ( 
"id_pendaftar" NUMBER(6,0),
```

This makes them case sensitive, so you have to use double quotes in your trigger, as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pendaftaran_tri 
BEFORE INSERT ON    MAHASISWA   
FOR EACH ROW      
  WHEN (new.id_pendaftar is null)  
DECLARE      v_daftar mahasiswa.id_pendaftar%NUMBER(8,0); 
BEGIN    
  SELECT MAHASISWA_SEQ.nextval INTO v_daftar 
  FROM DUAL;   
  :new."id_pendaftar" := v_daftar;      
END pendaftaran_tri;
```

However, I'd strongly advise against using case-sensitive column names. If possible, re-create your table with case-insensitive names, or ALTER your existing table.

Comment: i'm has almost 6 alter and re-create table